# Fulfill (don't resolve) promise with another promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I want to fulfill a promise with some other promise. The point is that I really want to get access to the (still pending) second *promise* as soon as the first promise is fulfilled. Unfortunately, I only seem to be able to get the second promise's resolution value once both both promises are fulfilled.

Here's the use case that I have in mind:

```
var picker = pickFile();

picker.then(  // Wait for the user to pick a file.
    function(downloadProgress) {
        // The user picked a file. The file may not be available just yet (e.g.,
        // if it has to be downloaded over the network) but we can already ask
        // the user some more questions while the file is being obtained in the
        // background.

        ...do some more user interaction...

        return downloadProgress;
    }
).then( // Wait for the download (if any) to complete.
    function(file) {
        // Do something with the file.
    }
)
```

The function `pickFile` displays a file picker where the user may pick a file either from their own hard drive or from a URL. It returns a promise `picker` that is fulfilled as soon as the user has picked a file. At this point, we may still have to download the selected file over the network. Therefore, I cannot fulfill `picker` with the selected file as resolution value. Instead, `picker` should be fulfilled with another promise, `downloadProgress`, which in turn will eventually be fulfilled with the selected file.

For completenes, here's a mock implementation of the `pickFile` function:

```
function pickFile() {
    ...display the file picker...

    var resolveP1 = null;

    var p1 = new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            resolveP1 = resolve;
        }
    );

    // Mock code to pretend the user picked a file
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var p2 = Promise.resolve('thefile');
        resolveP1(p2);  // <--- PROBLEM: I actually want to *fulfill* p1 with p2
    }, 3000);

    return p1;
}
```

The problem in the marked line is that I would like to *fulfill* the promise `p1` with the new promise `p2`, but I only know how to *resolve* it. The [difference between fulfilling and resolving](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) is that resolving first checks if the supplied value `p2` is again a promise. If it is, then fulfillment of `p1` will be deferred until `p2` is fulfilld, and then `p1` will be fulfilled with `p2`'s resolution value instead of `p2` itself.

I could work around this issue by building a wrapper around `p2`, i.e. by replacing the line

```
        resolveP1(p2);  // <--- PROBLEM: I actually want to *fulfill* p1 with p2
```

from the second code example by

```
        resolveP1({promise: p2});
```

Then, in the first code example, I'd have to replace the line

```
        return downloadProgress;
```

by

```
        return downloadProgress.promise;
```

But this seems like a bit of a hack when all I really want to do is just fulfill (instead of resolve) a promise.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Promises are unwrapped automatically, the only way to avoid that is to not resolve with another promise, as you mentioned. Is there a downside to resolving with a `result` object initially with the filename or other data initially, then having a `.file` function or property on there that resolves when it has uploaded?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with ES6 promises. I fear this will never be fixed, as the workaround is just too simple.

Comment: Is your sample a demonstrative scenario or is that your team use case? If that's your user case, your over complicating things. The only async operation here is the download, so have the file promisified, and do the rest in synchronous code. Once all synchronous code is done have a fulfilment function process the file.

Comment: @Amit: Maybe me calling it a "file picker" was misleading. It's not the modal "open file" dialog associated with an `<input type="file">`. Rather, `pickFile` displays a `<form>` with some input fields to select a file (locally or by URL) and a "continue" button. Thus, making `pickFile` synchronous would freeze the browser and the user wouldn't be able to interact with the form elements. Alternatively, returning a single promise from `pickFile` that is only resolved once the download finishes would mean that the user had to wait for the download even though the file isn't immediately needed.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: I guess, in this specific case, wrapping the returned promise in an object is viable, since I already know that the value I want to pass is a promise. I just thought that I was missing some obvious alternative since I thought fulfilling a promise with a value of _any_ type (be it a promise or not) was a rather generic thing to do and so I didn't expect it to be impossible. (Consider you're writing a library that wants to "return" some user-defined value from an async operation, where the library cannot make any assumptions about the type of the value). Thanks anyway!

Comment: No that's not what I meant. pickFile is obviously asynchronous, and returns a promise. That's fine. But after that's done, the rest looks like it could be synchronous. If you do that, and only attach the "then" handler once you're done with everything but the download, you'll get the behavior you need

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, I'm still having trouble to understand your solution. Are you suggesting to create the second promise from the main code (i.e. outside the `pickFile` function)? Then, the first promise (`picker`) would have to be resolved with some object that contains all the information needed to initiate the download and the main code would have to know about the implementation of the file picker (e.g., it would have to update a progress bar in the file picker,...). Sure it's possible but it creates a lot of dependencies. Or did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: In common terminology, "fulfill" means to put a promise in the "success" state (as opposed to "reject"). Given that, you cannot "fulfill" a promise with a promise. You can return a promise from a `.then`  handler and that will have the effect of essentially replacing the original promise with the returned promise. By the way, the term "resolve" is usually meant as either of fulfilling or rejecting.

Comment: This sort of problem can also happen with anything that has a method called `then()` on it, even if the `then()` method is not the same as a `Promise`'s `then()` and the object is not intended to be a `Promise`. Trying to resolve with it results in the `then()` method being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a solution apart from the workaround I already described in the question. For future reference, if you want to fulfill (rather than resolve) a promise `p` with a value `val`, where `val` is another promise, then just calling the promise resolution function for `p` with argument `val` won't work as expected. It would cause `p` to be "locked in" on the state of `val`, such that `p` will be fulfilled with `val`'s resolution value once `val` is fulfilled (see [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions)).

Instead, wrap `val` in another object and resolve `p` with that object:

```
var resolveP;  // Promise resolution function for p

var p = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
        resolveP = resolve;
    }
);

function fulfillPwithPromise(val) {  // Fulfills p with a promise val
    resolveP({promise: val});
}

p.then(function(res) {
    // Do something as soon as p is fulfilled...

    return res.promise;
}).then(function(res) {
    // Do something as soon as the second promise is fulfilled...
});
```

This solution works if you already know that `val` is a promise. If you cannot make any assumptions about `val`'s type, then you seem to be out of luck. Either you have to *always* wrap promise resolution values in another object, or you can try to detect whether `val` has a field `then` of type "function" and wrap it conditionally.

That said, in some cases the default behavior of promise resolution may actually have the desired effect. So only use the workaround described above if you are sure that you want to *fulfill* instead of *resolve* the first promise with the second one.

Comment: Probably would be a better idea to wait for more answers before accepting your own.

Comment: This Q&A deserves more up-votes. This is a HUGE shortcomming of native `Promise`s. Fortunately, the patch is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Although different people use different terms, in common terminology, "fulfill" means to put a promise in the "success" state (as opposed to "reject")--the state that will trigger then `then` handlers hanging off it.

In other words, you cannot "fulfill" a promise with a promise. You can fulfill it with a value. (By the way, the term "resolve" is usually meant as either of fulfilling or rejecting.)

What you can do is return a promise from a `.then` handler and that will have the effect of essentially replacing the original promise with the returned promise.

Here is a simple example of doing that:

```
asyncTask1 . then(asyncTask2) . then(processData)
```

where `asyncTask1` is a promise, and `asyncTask2` is a function which returns a promise. So when `asyncTask1` is fulfilled (done successfully), then `asyncTask2` runs, and the promise returned by the `.then` is "taken over" by the promise `asyncTask2` returns, so that when it finishes, the data can be processed.

I can do something similar by calling `Promise.resolve` with a promise as parameter. It's a bit of a misnomer, because I'm **not** resolving the promise in the technical sense. Instead, the new promise created is "inhabited" by the promise I passed in. It's also useless, because using the result is exactly the same as using the promise I passed in:

```
Promise.resolve(asyncTask2)
```

behaves exactly the same as

```
asyncTask2
```

(assuming asyncTask2 is already a promise; otherwise `Promise.resolve` has the effect of creating a promise which is immediately fulfilled with the passed in value.)

Just as you can pass a promise to `Promise.resolve`, you can pass a promise to the `resolve` function provided to you as a parameter of the promise constructor callback. If the parameter you pass to `resolve` is a non-promise, the promise immediately fulfills with that value. However, if the parameter you pass to `resolve` is another promise, that promise "takes over the body" of the promise you are constructing. To put it another way, the promise you are constructing starts to behave exactly as the the promise passed to `resolve`.

By "behave exactly" I mean, if the promise you pass in to `resolve` is already fulfilled, the promise you are constructing is instantly fulfilled with the same value. If the promise you pass in to `resolve` is already rejected, the promise you are constructing is instantly rejected with the same reason. If the promise you pass in to `resolve` is not resolved yet, then any `then` handlers you hang off the promise you are constructing will be invoked if and when the promise you pass to `resolve` is resolved.

Just as it is confusing that `Promise.resolve` may result in a promise which is not actually resolved, it is similarly confusing that calling the `resolve` function handed to you as a parameter to the promise constructor may **not** actually resolve the promise being constructed if you call it with an unresolved promise. Instead, as I've said a couple of times now, it has the effect of putting the promise being constructed in a state of total congruence with the promise passed to `resolve`.

Therefore, unless I am missing the point of your question, `pickfile` could be written as

```
function pickFile() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    ...display the file picker...

    // Mock code to pretend the user picked a file
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('thefile');
    });
}
```

I didn't really understand your question clearly, so this might not be what you want. Please clarify if you care to.

Comment: I think the OP does understand the difference between resolving and fulfilling quite well. He does want to fullfill with a promise, as a promise is just a value.

Comment: I realize that, colloquially, "fulfilling" and "resolving" a promise are sometimes used as synonyms. I was using the terms in the sense of the [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects), which makes a clear distinction between the two. In this sense, the `resolve` function is named correctly, as the spec states: "A promise is resolved if it is settled or if it has been 'locked in' to match the state of another promise." (where "settled" means "either fulfilled or rejected".)

Comment: The problem with your implementation is that the file may not be available immediately after the user picked it. If it still has to be downloaded then I want to have the download initiated and monitored by `pickFile`, but I still want to fulfill the promise that is returned by `pickFile` immediately after the user picked a file (the download should continue in the background).

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar solution in the process of moving away from Angular's $q to the native Promise feature. `Promise.all` could be an option (in cases of independent parallel async tasks) by passing around an appropriate object, or something decorated with the state, passing it off to whatever is ready when appropriate. In the Promise.all sample below note how it recovers in one of the promises--took me awhile to realize how to redirect the result of a chain. The result of the all is just the last promise's return. While this doesn't answer the question's title, using `return Promise.reject(<an-object-including-a-promise>)` (or resolve) gives a series and/or group of async tasks shared access and control along the way. In the case of picking, downloading then working with a file I'd take out the progress-event handling then do: `pickFile.then(download,orFailGracefully)` with `downloadProgress` handled within the `download` onResolve handler (download-progress doesn't appear to be an async task). Below are related experiments in the console.

```
var q = {
defer: function _defer(){
    var deferred = { };
    deferred.promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        deferred.resolve = resolve;
        deferred.reject = reject;
    });
    return deferred;
    }
};

var communityThatCares = q.defer();
communityThatCares.promise.then(function(someGood){
    console.log('someGood', someGood);
    return someGood;
}, function(someBad){
    console.warn('someBad', someBad);
    return someBad;
});

(new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ communityThatCares.about = 'communityThatCares'; setTimeout(resolve,1000, communityThatCares); }))
.then(
function(e){
    console.log(3,e); return e.resolve(e);
}, function(e){
    console.warn(3, e); return e.reject(e);
});

var todo = {
    find:'swan'
};

var greaterGood = [(
(new Promise(function(res,rej){ res(todo); })).then(function(e){ e.stuff = 'things'; return e; }),
(new Promise(function(res,reject){ 
    reject(todo);
})).then(function(e){ return e; }
,function(e){
    console.warn(1,e);
    e.recover = 'uh oh';
    return Promise.resolve(e);
}).then(function(e){ console.log(2,e); return e; }),
(new Promise(function(res,rej){ res(todo); })).then(function(e){ console.log(1,e); e.schedule = 'today'; return e; },function(e){ console.warn(1,e); return e; }).then(function(e){ console.log(2,e); return e; }))
];

var nkay = Promise.all( greaterGood )
.then(function(todo){
    console.log('all',todo[0]); return todo;
}, function(todo){
    console.warn('all',todo[0]); return todo;
});
```

Comment: May I suggest to [avoid the deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572), or is this an intentional part of your solution?

Comment: Helpful stuff @Bergi. Before an edit: The question is unclear but seems to be "how to resolve (or reject) a promise with another promise or object" which is what my answer tries to address. The sample code doesn't seem to be the best approach for the somewhat vague problem stated, ie mixing progress events with async request/promises doesn't make sense to me. Would it be best remove the answer or just adjust from Promise.all to promise.then.then chain (or something else?)? Thanks!