# Typescript error when function return type is Promise<{ then: () => void }>

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I cant declare function, that returns promise to [Derivable](https://ds300.github.io/derivablejs/#derivable-Derivable). Reason is next:

[Minimal exmaple in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Some%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20then(callback)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20foo()%3A%20Promise%3CSome%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20ok()%3A%20Promise%3Cnumber%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%2042%3B%0D%0A%7D)

```
interface Some {
  then(callback);
}

// Error: the return type of an async function must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable 'then' member.
async function foo(): Promise<Some> {
  return null;
}
```

Is it bug in typescript? Is any workaround awailable? I cant use async/await because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not a bug in Typescript. It's just [fundamentally impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572) to fulfill a promise with a [thenable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29437927/1048572) (an object with a `then` method), as it tries to assimilate it when resolving. As a workaround, you can wrap the `Derivable` in an extra object, as a proper solution I would recommend renaming `then` to [`chain`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that typescript cannot recognize the different signature of the method `then` because you kinda overrided it in the interface.