# Promise returning a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

Suppose that `x` is a `Promise`. Then `Promise.resolve(x)` is exactly the same thing as `x`. However, I would like to create a `Promise` that returns a `Promise`, i.e., some function `magic` such that `magic(x)` is a fullfilled `Promise` whose value is `x`.

Using TypeScript annotation for better clarity:

```
let x : Promise<number> = whatever();
let y : Promise<number> = Promise.resolve(x);
let z : Promise<Promise<number>> = magic(x);
Console.assert(x === y);
z.then(function (a) {
  Console.assert(x === a);
});
```

How can `magic` be implemented?

The same question can be asked for the `Promise.then` method, but I guess that the answer would be pretty similar.

Comment: You would need to use an algebraic promise library such as [Creed](http://blog.briancavalier.com/creed/) where you can use `Promise.of(Promise.of(someValue))`, the `then` and `resolve` methods of A+ compatible libraries can never do this

Comment: For the record, inspired by answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/807307, I ended up defining `z` as `Promise<[Promise<number>]>` and packing and unpacking the inner promise each time I had to. It is a bit ugly, but the array around the inner promise prevents the outer promise to resolve to it. It seems to work.