# How to return a Promise from async function?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

When I try to return a promise from an async function, it's impossible to distinguish the status of the returned Promise and the function.

I think, the simplest solution is to put the promise to be returned in an array. The following is a stupid example, but I hope it demonstrates the problem:

```
function loadMetaData(id) {/*...*/} // Returns Promise<MetaData>
function loadSingleData(name) {/*...*/} // Returns Promise<SingleData>

async function startLoadingSingleData(id, object) {
    const metaData = object.metaData = await loadMetadata(id);
    const singleDataPromise = loadSingleData(metaData.dataToLoad);
    singleDataPromise.then(metaData => object.metaData = metaData);
    return [singleDataPromise];
}

async function logData(id) {
    const object = new SomeUsefulClassWhatTakesAdvantageOfMetadataProp();
    somePromise = (await startLoadingSingleData(id))[0];
    // Now metadata surely loaded, do something with it
    console.log(object.metaData);
    // But somedata will be loaded only in future
    somePromise.then(singleData => console.log(singleData));

    // And maybe: (depends of use-case)
    await somePromise;
}
```

When executing `logData(/*...*/)`, first the `metaData` of the given ID of the given data after a short period, and after a little waiting the full `singleData` is expected.

But this is kinda hackish.

What is the intended way to overcome this situation?

PS.:
This problem occurs too, when I try to return a Promise which resolves with the promise.

Comment: "t's impossible to distinguish the status of the returned Promise and the function" — I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: "the simplest solution is to put the promise to be returned in an array" — Async functions must return a promise, not an array, not even if that array contains a promise.

Comment: async functions return a Promise automatically. Whatever value you return from your async function is going to be wrapped in a Promise automatically. If you literally do `async function() { return new Promise(...) }`, you are actually returning a Promise of a Promise. Unless that's what you need, you don't need to create the promise yourself, just return your value.

Comment: Thank all of you, updated. I hope now this clarifies the need of returning a promise, and what I mean by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `startLoadingSingleData` has too many responsibilities. It is responsible for both loading the metadata and triggering loading of singledata.

Your `logData` function uses `await startLoadingSingleData(id)` as a way to make sure that metadata is available, which does not seem very intuituve. It is not obvious that `startLoadingSingleData(id)` returns a Promise that resolves when the metadata has loaded, and would be quite confusing for a coder looking at it for the first time (or yourself after a few months). Code should be self-documenting as much as possible so that you don't need to explain every line with comments.

My recommendation is to completely remove the `startLoadingSingleData` function and just do this inside `logData`:

```
async function logData(id) {
    const metaData = await loadMetadata(id);
    console.log(metaData);

    const singleData = await loadSingleData(metaData.name);
    console.log(singleData);
}
```

or if you don't want logData to `await` the SingleData Promise:

```
async function logData(id) {
    const metaData = await loadMetadata(id);
    console.log(metaData);

    loadSingleData(metaData.name).then( singleData => {
        console.log(singleData);
    } );
}
```

If you really want to keep using the function `startLoadingSingleData` instead then I think you should make it return an array or an object containing two Promises:

```
function startLoadingSingleData(id) {
    const metaDataLoaded = loadMetadata(id);
    const singleDataLoaded = metaDataLoaded.then(
      metaData => loadSingleData(metaData.dataToLoad)
    );

    return { metaDataLoaded, singleDataLoaded };
}
```

Then your usage would look something like:

```
async function logData(id) {
    const { metaDataLoaded, singleDataLoaded } = startLoadingSingleData(id);

    const metaData = await metaDataLoaded;
    console.log(metaData);

    const singleData = await singleDataLoaded;
    console.log(singleData);
}
```

Comment: OK, I forgot: there [is a problem with the final snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) that does `a, b = getPromises(); await a; await b;`. When `loadMetaData` rejects, you would get an unhandled promise rejection from the `singleDataLoaded` promise :-(

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unfortunately JS promises are not algebraic and [you cannot fulfill a promise with another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572). There's no way around that (other than  not using native promises, and not using `async`/`await`).

The easiest and most common solution is indeed using a wrapper object. It comes naturally to your problem:

```
// takes an id, returns a Promise<{metaData: Data, singleDataPromise: Promise<Data>}>
async function startLoadingSingleData(id) {
    const object = new SomeUsefulClassWhatTakesAdvantageOfMetadataProp();
    object.metaData = await loadMetadata(id);
//                    ^^^^^
    object.singleDataPromise =   loadSingleData(object.metaData.dataToLoad);
//                             ^ no await here
    return object;
}
async function logData(id) {
    const object = await startLoadingSingleData(id));
    // Now metadata surely loaded, do something with it
    console.log(object.metaData);
    // But some singleData will be loaded only in future
    const singleData = await object.singleDataPromise;
    console.log(singleData);
}
```

Notice that this potentially leads to problems with unhandled rejections if there is an exception in your code and you never get to `await` the `singleDataPromise`.

The (probably much better) alternative is to restructure your functions so that you don't create any promises before using (i.e. awaiting) them, like @Paulpro also suggested. So you'd just write a single strictly sequential function

```
async function logData(id) {
    const object = new SomeUsefulClassWhatTakesAdvantageOfMetadataProp();
    object.metaData = await loadMetadata(id);
    // Now metadata surely loaded, do something with it
    console.log(object.metaData);
    // But some singleData will be loaded only in future
    object.singleData = await loadSingleData(object.metaData.dataToLoad);
    console.log(object.singleData);
}
```