# Is it possible that async function returns object having "then" function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

The JavaScript async function(or regular function that returns Promise) regards any object that has function with "then" field as a Promise. So is it impossible to let such object as a resolved value of Promise?

Example: The function call `await f()` does not return result. If the field name of `then` is different name, it returns result.

```
async function f() {
    return {
        then() {
            //This function is just a function that somehow the name "then" is appropriate for.
            return 42;
        }
    };
}
async function main() {
    let result=await f();// it stops here.
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.then());
}
main();
```

Comment: If you check the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302826/1825844, you can see that the async function automatically creates a wrapper Promise as well as step through the return chain of Promises till it fully resolved.

Comment: Indeed this is impossible. See also [Fulfill (don't resolve) promise with another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572) and [How to return a Promise from async function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49541574/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation about [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#syntax) you will notice

> `await expression`
>
> **expression**
>
> A `Promise`, a `thenable` object, or any value to wait for.

And then you follow to the [`thenable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables) docs, you will find that

> A thenable implements the `.then()` method

and

> To interoperate with the existing Promise implementations, the language allows using thenables in place of promises.

So, the combination of `await` and returning an object with a `then` method suggests to the js engine that this is a thenable object. So it expects it to have correctly implemented the `thenable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

an async function always returns a Promise, so you're returning a Promise that returns an object with a `.then` method - but a proper .then method takes two arguments, both functions. `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` - your `then` function is not a valid Promise then

To make it work, you'd write it something like this instead

```js
async function f() {
    return {
        then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
            onFulfilled(42);
        }
    };
}
async function main() {
    let result=await f();
    console.log(result);
    f().then(result => console.log(result));
}
main();
```

Comment: Yes, I know this works. I am developing a development environment, and I do not intend to write this code (an object with a function named "then") myself, but I want to be able let users of my environment write code that will treat "then" as just a function, without having to advise them "do not create object having function named 'then' ".

Comment: oh, I misunderstood the question @hoge1e3 - I thought you wanted the code to work!