# Resolving a Promise within a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Consider the example:

```js
let promiseA = new Promise((res, rej) => res(10));
let promiseB = new Promise((res, rej) => res(promiseA))

promiseB.then((resolvedVal) => console.log(resolvedVal)); //Outputs 10;
```

I expect *resolvedVal* to be *promiseA*, and not the resolved value of *promiseA*. Why is this not the case?

I understand this has something to do with the automatic "unwrapping" of promises, but I would like some insight on what exactly is happening under the hood.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168194/fulfill-dont-resolve-promise-with-another-promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Promise((res, rej) => res(promiseA))` is known as [promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and there is never a good reason to do that.

This code

```
let promiseB = new Promise((res, rej) => res(promiseA))
```

is equivalent to

```
let promiseB = promiseA;
```

> I expect resolvedVal to be promiseA, and not the resolved value of promiseA. Why is this not the case?

This is how promises work and a reason why this pattern is useful to avoid callback hell. A promise of a value becomes a value when a promise is chained with `then`.

As [Promise/A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure) states:

> The promise resolution procedure is an abstract operation taking as input a promise and a value, which we denote as [[Resolve]](promise, x). If x is a thenable, it attempts to make promise adopt the state of x, under the assumption that x behaves at least somewhat like a promise. Otherwise, it fulfills promise with the value x.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, you can't return a promise from a promise.  It will always chain and resolve/reject.  Try this:

```
let promiseA = new Promise((res, rej) => res(10));
let promiseB = new Promise((res, rej) => res([promiseA]))

promiseB.then((resolvedVal) => console.log(resolvedVal));
//Outputs [promiseA]
```

;

Comment: Why is there a reason to 'try this'?

Comment: The question asked why a promise was expected but not returned.  This demonstrates how to not resolve the returned promise.