# Asynchronous Generators in Javascript: is there a difference between yielding a Promise and yielding an awaited Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, generator

I'm taking a look at the asynchronous generators proposed in ES9 to be able to grasp the logic.

Since each yielded value is used as value property in the returned object - wrapped by a Promise - from a next() call:

```
async function * asyncGen() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2; 
}

let asyncIterator = asyncGen();

asyncIterator.next(); // Promise fullfilled with {value: 1, done: false}

asyncIterator.next(); // Promise fullfilled with {value: 2, done: false}
```

I thought this was true also for yielded Promises:

```
async function * asyncGen() {
    yield Promise.resolve(3);
    yield new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 10000));
}

let asyncIterator = asyncGen();

asyncIterator.next();
// Expected: Promise fullfilled with {value: Promise fullfilled with 3, done: false}
// Get: Promise fullfilled with {value: 3, done: false}

asyncIterator.next();
// Expected: Promise fullfilled with
// {value: Promise pending for 10 seconds, then fullfilled with undefined, done: false}
// Get: Promise pending for 10 seconds,
// then fullfilled with {value: undefined, done: false}
```

So the promises are merged together. This doesn't sound bad, but I don't expected that because of:

```
async function * asyncGen() {
    yield await Promise.resolve(3);
    yield await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 10000));
}

let asyncIterator = asyncGen();

asyncIterator.next(); // Promise fullfilled with {value: 3, done: false}

asyncIterator.next(); 
// Promise pending for 10 seconds,
// then fullfilled with {value: undefined, done: false}
```

Here merging is more reasonable because *await* cannot stop the generator, *next()* call have to return a Promise. But that Promise could be fullfilled only when the awaited Promise into the generator is fullfilled.

So is the keyword *await* completely useless used with the keyword *yield* in the same expression or am I missing something important?

Comment: Yes, it appears useless, just like [`return await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572). This is because we [can't have a promise for a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572), which would be weird in `for await (… of …)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async generators unwrap yielded promises to avoid a promise (the one returned by the **next method**, for example) of promise (the one inside the value field).
A concept from which the JavaScript lang always kept away.

Answer (score 0):

> One interesting aspect of combining await and yield is that await can’t stop yield from returning a Promise, but it can stop that Promise from being settled:

```
async function* asyncGenerator() {
    console.log('Start');
    const result = await doSomethingAsync(); // (A)
    yield 'Result: '+result; // (B)
    console.log('Done');
}
```

[ES2018: asynchronous iteration](http://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html) by Dr. Axel Rauschmayer

Comment: Thanks but I'm not speaking about this particular case. I agree with the possibility of stopping the returned promise using await, because is the only reasonable thing that could happen.