# Nested promise resolution method

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

In the code below when I call func I get back a promise that resolves after 3 seconds which resolves to another promise.  The nested promise then resolves to the number 43 after an additional 3 seconds.  My question is why the console.log returns res:43 after 6 seconds instead of unresolved promise after 3 seconds.  I .then func2 but I never .then otherFunc

```
async function func(){
  const val = func2().then((other)=>{console.log("res:"+other)})
}

async function func2(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(otherfunc()),3000)

  })
}
async function otherfunc(){
  return  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(43),3000)

  })
}
```

Comment: The question is not really clear, can you rephrase please? *"My question is why the console.log returns res:43 after 6 seconds instead of unresolved promise after 3 seconds"*

Comment: also no need to use async if you're not using await

Comment: Because both func2 and otherFunc wait for 3 seconds: `3*2 = 6`

Comment: When do do `.then()` on a value which is `Promise.resolve(someOtherPromise)`, that one `.then()` will wait for both promises, the original and someOtherPromise.  They are chained together.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly [what "resolve" means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572). You can't [fulfill a promise with a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572)

Comment: Thanks everyone I figured that was what was happening I just didn't realize that .then would wait for all promises in the chain to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you resolve `func2` with another promise which is `otherfunc()`, so `func2` happens to resolve after 3 seconds, which then calls `otherfunc` which also resolves after 3 seconds. The result you see at your `console.log` statement shows 43 because the `.then()` will wait for all promises to complete.