# Is it possible for an 'await' to resolve to a Promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await

If I have an async-function which contains an explicit return statement which returns a Promise, what will be the value of an await expression calling such a function?

Does the await resolve to the value given by the explicit return-expression of the async-function, or does it resolve to what that value resolves to in case it is a Promise?

I know there are already questions related to this topic on Stack Overflow, but I would just like a precise answer to this question: "Is it possible for an 'await' to resolve to a Promise?". Yes or No? Of course if you can also explain why or why not, that would be very helpful.

Comment: The whole point with async/await is to give syctactic sugar to Promises

Comment: "*an explicit return statement which returns a Promise*" - you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353087/1048572) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38708550/1048572) question about what happens there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible for an `await` expression to result in a promise.

Just like you [cannot fulfill a promise with another promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32168194/1048572), and like `then()` never calling the fulfillment handler with a promise.

Comment: So if the explicit return statement of an async -function returns a Promise, then the value of the await -expression in the caller of that function would resolve into what the explicitly returned promise would resolve to, not to that promise. Right?

Comment: Yes. The `await` expression never even sees the inner promise, it only sees the promise that is [immediately created by the call to the `async function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431/1048572). When (later) the `return` statement is executed, it just [resolves](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572) that first ("outer") promise with the inner promise, which causes the first promise to [fulfill/reject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572) with the same value later. Only when that happens, the `await` is notified to resume the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `async` syntax, that means that the function will return a `Promise`. The `async/await` is just a different syntax for handling `Promises`, which allow you to write `synchronous-like` code.

So, it is the same if you return a value from `async` function, or you return a `resolved/rejected Promise` from `non-async` function.

Comment: That is very helpful. I read somewhere too that the async-function will (always) "return a Promise". My confusion was as to which promise is returned, who creates that promise, and when and when not.  It now seems clear to me that if the async-function explicitly returns a Promise, then no NEW promise will be created around that.

Answer (score -1):

If you define the function with `async`, it wraps a `Promise` around whatever the function body returns.

If the function does `return new Promise(...)` then that `Promise` will be wrapped in another `Promise` added by `async`.

`await` resolves a Promise, but if the `Promise` contains another `Promise`, the value of the `await` expression will be the nested `Promise`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly it seems you are saying the answer is YES, it is possible for await to resolve to a Promise?

Comment: Yes, if the promise resolves to another promise.

Comment: Voted down as this seems to be wrong, based on my own experiments and other answers.